# Publishing and packaging code with MSBuild.exe

Tags: msbuild

Hi I need to publish my code using MSbuild.exe and create a package of the publish code to a location.

Need to understand how target file will work and the arguments I need to pass while calling the MSbuild.exe

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish? Creating a package and then publishing it to IIS?

Comment: I just need to publish the code and keep it in a folder, deploying it to IIS is next step but I want to keep the published code at a location. Like in visual studio we do publish code, and it gets published to a folder, I am want the same scenario to be accomplished by msbuild.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to keep code in a folder the better way to do it is to package it since your intentions are to deploy it to IIS later. That way the deployment will process will be easier and clean.

Below is the command to create and save package to desired location:

**msbuild "Your\Solution\location\YourSolution.sln" /t:build /P:configuration="Debug-Dev" /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:DeployOnBuild=True  /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:PackageLocation="\wherever\you\want"**

Comment: Thnx Nagendara, yes I was looking for the same solution and I got it working by searching with some better keywords on the internet.